# Invoiced Line Items ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms, invoice

I have an invoice form . As you know it has Header and Line Items . When user creates invoice there can be any numner of line items.So users can click "Add Item" to add a new item and all of them needs to be saved together when user save the item.

I think I should use Grid view inside update panel with a footer row to add a new row. And save it to a table in session.When they click save invoice I can get the table from session and save those line items.

Let me know for any better approach than this.

Comment: Looks like a good start.  Be wary of session variables though, your user may expect his work is being saved as he goes, and if he walks away in the middle of filling out an order and comes back two hours later to find his session has expired and his data is lost, he may be unhappy.

Comment: I agree with Kendrick. Maybe you could store the user's shopping cart into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would create custom forms and *add* button that will add another line of items.

You can use jQuery append to insert **div** to existing container that contains all the normal fields:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //dynamicId for text box's id
    var dynamicId = 0        

    //event handler for Add button
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        dynamicId += 1            

        //append <div> elements inside existing container which has
        //the all fields
        $('#invoiceItemsContainer').append('<div><input type="text" id="txt' + dynamicId + 'runat="server" /></div>');
    });
});
```

When the form submitted, you can extract all the data from the text box. You do need to come up with a way to check how many line of items are on the list, but this is easy enough for you to figure out.